# Show a modal in Adobe XD

Tags: adobe-xd

I have a modal in a layer above everything else. I need to add a click to a button that shows the modal.  How do I do this?  Everything I've seen online involves adding multiple artboards. I just need to show and hide a layer on click.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What do you mean by "a modal"?

Comment: Here's a good article to explain what a modal is.
https://blog.hubspot.com/website/modal-web-design

Comment: I see. So my answer should still work for this, as it can be used to show or hide anything basically.

Answer (score 0):

One possible method would be to use a component toggle state.

1. Make a button, and add an image or a group containing the content you want to show or hide. Select both. Make it a component.
2. Add a component toggle state, by clicking the + button next to the default state.
3. In the defaule state, set the image/group opacity to 0%
4. In the toggle state, set the image/group opacity to 100%

That's it really. Just preview it to try it out.

An example

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, that way allows you to click anywhere on the screen to show it.  Not just the button.